# Are there any triple equals === methods outside of Cats in Scala?

Tags: scala, equals, scalaz, scala-cats, triple-equals

I have spent a while searching on Google for a non-Cats triple equals method, but can't find anything apart from Scalaz. Unfortunately, I have been unable to work out the import for `===` in this library.

Can someone help, many thanks.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Why are you looking for usages of `===`? If you are able to elaborate on your question, you may get more relevant answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding scalaz try

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

42 === "hello" // error: type mismatch; found: String("hello") required: Int
```

where

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalaz" %% "scalaz-core" % "7.2.28"
```

Answer (score 6):

If all you need is `===`, you could very easily mimic the behaviour from Cats with your own function:

```scala
implicit class AnyWithTripleEquals[T](a: T) {
  def ===(b: T): Boolean = a equals b
}

/*
scala> "2" === "3"
res0: Boolean = false

scala> "2" === 3
<console>:13: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(3)
 required: String
       "2" === 3
*/
```

Comment: This is great thank you, its just that I am running wartremoval through my code and equals is disabled as well as ==

Answer (score 4):

Of the top of my head other libraries that use `===` are e.g.:

- Slick uses `===` for `=` in queries - http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.3.1/queries.html
- matchers in test frameworks e.g. https://github.com/etorreborre/specs2/blob/8305db76c5084e4b3ce5827ce23117f6fb6beee4/matcher/shared/src/main/scala/org/specs2/matcher/TypedEqual.scala use `===` to check assertions and (usually) raise assertion error, sometimes with some nice diff (scalatest I think?)

but it isn't the same use case as in Cats/Scalaz.

If you want to use it in Cats you need:

- syntax - `import cats.syntax.eq._` or `import cats.syntax.all._` or `import cats.implicits._` (if you duplicate import of syntax, Scala won't be able to resove it)
- instance - if you compare 2 `A` you need an implicit instance of `cats.Eq[A]`. instances for `List`s, `Map`s etc. can be found in `cats.instances.list._`, `cats.instances.map._`, `cats.instances.all._` or `cats.implicits._` (same rule as above). There should be instances for all "normal" types but if you have your own, you need to either provide `Eq` instance on your own or derive it with something like [Kittens](https://github.com/typelevel/kittens).

If you are missing some implicit (or if some implicit is ambiguous, because you imported the same things from 2 different places) the syntax won't work.

Same thing about Scalaz though imports and type classes will have other names.

If you don't mind some performance penalty (caused by `isInstanceOf` inside `equals`) and lack of flexibility regarding the definition of equality check, you can use @sachav's solution.

Answer (score 4):

Another library that provides `===` is [scalactic](http://www.scalactic.org), which is basically a set of utilities used by ScalaTest, which are packaged as a separate lib.

```
import org.scalactic._
import TypeCheckedTripleEquals._

"Hello" === "Hello" //true
1 === "Hello" //won't compile
```

you can also "configure" how your equality is being resolved with implicits:

```
import org.scalactic._
import TripleEquals._
import StringNormalizations._
import Explicitly._

implicit val strEquality = decided by defaultEquality[String] afterBeing lowerCased

"Hello" === "hello"                           // true
"normalized" === "NORMALIZED"                 // true
```

Comment: TypeCheckedTripleEquals._ might be necessary for compile time check.

Comment: Thank you, hopefully this has an import for comparing Option[String] s